# ZeroMQ - running same task on x remote workers and collecting results on the client

Tags: architecture, network-programming, zeromq, distributed-computing

I have a scenario where i have an client that needs to **simultaneously** run an async task on x workers (each worker has a ZeroMQ socket binding on a remote machine).

So it would be a single request to several endpoints:

```
10.0.0.7 REQ ----> 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3, 10.0.04 (Task)
```

Each endpoint would send back the progress and the final result when done.

```
10.0.0.2 REP ----> 10.0.0.7 (25%)
10.0.0.2 REP ----> 10.0.0.7 (50%)
10.0.0.3 REP ----> 10.0.0.7 (45%)
10.0.0.3 REP ----> 10.0.0.7 (75%)
10.0.0.4 REP ----> 10.0.0.7 (45%)
10.0.0.2 REP ----> 10.0.0.7 (Result)
10.0.0.3 REP ----> 10.0.0.7 (Result)
10.0.0.4 REP ----> 10.0.0.7 (Result)
10.0.0.7 - Save all results received
```

So the same logical task should run at the same time on x machines, and then each machine should send back several progress replies, and then a final result of computing that specific task. Once all results from all machines are received, the results should be stored on the client and the logical task is done.

So far i have figured out the following possible approaches with ZeroMQ:

1. Use ZeroMQ polling over multiple sockets (each socket connected to one endpoint), and when all results are back close all connections.
2. Use Dealer-Router pairs for each connection (to be able to get multiple replies from the workers), run them in parallel. This seems like it would work well, since i could control individual connections better.
3. Use a pub-sub architecture.

In addition, the client should be able to stop-restart tasks on specific boxes, so it doesn't have to be necessarily a single REQ to the workers (there can be additional REQ for restart etc.).

All approaches would include some reliability mechanism of course and proper error handling.

Not sure what approach would be optimal. I wonder if somebody implemented something similar in ZeroMQ and what would be the architectural recommendation?